# Selecting all columns using distinct against one specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I appreciate that this question has been asked before but I am struggling to find an answer that will even run within Oracle 10g (10.2.0.5.0)

I have a table called `BASIC` which contains approximately 70 columns. Currently, I return a specified number of rows using the following code (as an example) - the result being the first 20 members who have a `MEMBNO` after 5000

```
SELECT * FROM BASIC WHERE MEMBNO>5000 AND ROWNUM <=20 ORDER BY MEMBNO;
```

Within the 20 rows returned, several of the rows have the same value in the `NINO` column

I would like to modify my `SELECT` statement to return the next 20 rows with distinct/unique `NINO` values

Simply wrapping a `DISTINCT` around the * gives me an `ORA-00936: missing expression` error, plus it would not be as precise as I would like.

Comment: with dis as (select distinct membno, nino from basic where membno > 5000 and rownum <= 20) select * from basic b, dis where dis.membno = b.membno and dis.nino = b.nino order by b.memno   ...but the join should be on the primary key

Comment: Apologies for that @a_horse_with_no_name - an oversight on my part. I will endeavour to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution via another source

This shows the rows where there are duplicates...

```
select * from basic where rowid not in (select min(rowid) from basic group by nino)
```

This shows the rows with the duplicate rows removed...

```
select * from basic where rowid in (select min(rowid) from basic group by nino)
```

Then I can add my row count and membno filters for the final result...

```
select * from basic where rowid in (select min(rowid) from basic where membno>6615 group by NINO) and rownum <=20 order by membno;
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the code below:- I have used analytical query concept to fetch only distinct nino values.

```
     select * from 
        (SELECT b.*,row_number() over (partition by nino order by MEMBNO  ) rn 
FROM BASIC b WHERE MEMBNO>5000)
 where rn =1 AND ROWNUM <=20 ORDER BY MEMBNO;
```

Let me know in case you encounter any issues.

Comment: Thanks @user2342436 - the code you posted seems to run fine. I will need to examine the actual results to ensure it is returning what I want. I did find another solution which I'm posting as an answer